# Count the amount of times a value appears combined with a certain event

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, countif

I basically have the following list:

[image: https://gyazo.com/9d96cb091c2f30f17a2894b5284feb4b]

How can I count the amount of times John won?

I have tried using both countif and countifs but have find no positive result. I either get "#VALUE!" or a simple "0"

I'm still new to this but I couldn't find an answer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula to count how many times John has won:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"John",C:C,"Won")`

Or use this dynamic formula in D2 and apply to all rows (you will have their winning count repeat next to any occurrence of their name):

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Won")`

Adding the D column to your example, it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried using both the formulas you told me but I receive an ERROR:508

Comment: I've tested this in Excel. Are you using Excel or opening an Excel file in another application?

Comment: Oh I'm using openoffice calc. I thought they both had the same basic formulas

Comment: I suppose the equivalent function would be `=COUNTIFS(A:A;"John";C:C;"Won")` but I cannot test it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your help I used =CONT.SES(A1:A6;"John";C1:C6;"Won") which is basically =COUNTIFS(A1:A6;"John";C1:C6;"Won") but in portuguese.  Do I need to do something to mark this question as "ANSWERED"?

Comment: If my answer helped than please mark it as answered. You should at least tag this question with `libreoffice-calc` to clarify it refers to LibreOffice Calc and not Microsoft Excel as I mistakenly assumed.